# Error 500 cuando intento guardar datos sql node js react

Tags: javascript, sql, nodejs, reactjs, orm

uso nodejs con react y ya había realizado todo el proceso de guardar en bd, funcionaba todo perfecto, después de unos dias volvi a probarlo y me sale error 500 en una parte pero la otra funciona, no tengo ni idea de que paso, el error 500 me sale en el navegador pero en consola no parece nada.
uso docker y sql por lo que tengo mac.
esta seria la base de datos, la idea es que segun el tipo de mensaje e interesado, pueda editar el contenido para después consultar el contenido y usarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el controloller tengo

```
  async updateMensaje(request){

    // Context
    const serviceLocator = request.server.app.serviceLocator;

    // Input
    const { tipoMensaje, tipoInteresado, contenido, imageTemplate} = request.payload;
    // console.log("Estamos en mensajeControloller ",tipoMensaje, tipoInteresado, contenido, imageTemplate);

    // Treatment
    const mensaje = await UpdateMensaje(tipoMensaje, tipoInteresado, contenido, imageTemplate, serviceLocator);

    // Output
    return true;

  },
```

esta es UpdateMensaje

```
'use strict';

const Mensaje = require('../../../domain/mensaje/Mensaje');

module.exports = (TipoMensaje, TipoInteresado, Contenido, ImagenTemplate, { mensajeRepository }) => {
  const mensaje = new Mensaje(null, TipoMensaje, TipoInteresado, Contenido, ImagenTemplate,);
  console.log("datos actualizados -->   ", mensaje);
  return mensajeRepository.merge(mensaje);
};
```

y el merge

```
  async merge(mensajeEntity) {
 
    const { IdMensaje,TipoMensaje, TipoInteresado, Contenido, ImagenTemplate} = mensajeEntity;

    const seqMensaje = await this.model.findOne({ where: { TipoMensaje: TipoMensaje, TipoInteresado: TipoInteresado} })
    console.log("que esta pasando we ",seqMensaje.dataValues );
    console.log("tipomensaje-> ",TipoMensaje==TipoMensaje, " tipointeresado ",TipoInteresado== TipoInteresado)
    if (!seqMensaje) return false;
    await seqMensaje.update({ IdMensaje, TipoMensaje, TipoInteresado, Contenido, ImagenTemplate });
    return new Mensaje(seqMensaje.IdMensaje, seqMensaje.TipoMensaje, seqMensaje.TipoInteresado, seqMensaje.Contenido, seqMensaje.ImagenTemplate);
  }
```

Lo raro es que cuando selecciono los 4 últimos, desde el front, es decir correoElectronico con algún otro tipodeInteresado, el funciona y me edita el contenido, pero con los primeros me marca error 500.

Pero en consola me muestra lo siguiente.
Estoy seleccionando la primera fila de la base de datos, por lo que veo me recibe bien los datos pero me saca error 500, mientras que si realizo lo mismo pero con los 4 inferiores no me sale ningun error y funciona perfectamente.

```
datos actualizados -->    {
  IdMensaje: null,
  TipoMensaje: 'sms',
  TipoInteresado: 'Cliente',
  Contenido: 'Mensaje de texto y cliente',
  ImagenTemplate: ''
}
que esta pasando we  {
  IdMensaje: 1,
  TipoMensaje: 'sms',
  TipoInteresado: 'Cliente',
  Contenido: 'sms cliente',
  ImagenTemplate: null
}
tipomensaje->  true  tipointeresado  true
```

pero esto es lo que aparece en el navegador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en orm tengo este modelo

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

    sequelize.define('Mensaje', {
        IdMensaje:{
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            allowNull: false
        },
        TipoMensaje:{
            // type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:false
        },
        TipoInteresado:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:false
        },
        Contenido:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:false
        },       
        ImagenTemplate:{
            type: DataTypes.BLOB,
            allowNull:false
        }
    }, {
      freeseTableName: true,
      tableName: 'Mensaje',
      timestamps: false
    });
  
  };
```

aqui muestro la consola del back, en esta realice 2 peticiones la primera funciona mienetras la segunda, nop.

```
POST    /ubicacion                                      Create ubicacion                                 
GET     /ubicacion/{id}                                 Get ubicacion by its {id}                        
DELETE  /ubicacion/{id}                                 Delete ubicacion                                 
POST    /updatemensaje                                  Update mensaje                                   
GET     /usuario                                        List all usuarios                                
POST    /usuario                                        Create usuario                                   
GET     /usuario/{id}                                   Get usuario by its {id}                          
DELETE  /usuario/{id}                                   Delete usuario                                   
GET     /version                                        List all version                                 

Servidor corriendo en: http://la-MacBook-Pro-de-Juan.local:3000
(node:19556) Warning: `config.options.trustServerCertificate` will default to false in the future. To silence this message, specify a value explicitly in the config options
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:19556) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.
Connection has been established successfully.
datos actualizados -->    {
  IdMensaje: null,
  TipoMensaje: 'correoElectronico',
  TipoInteresado: 'Cliente',
  Contenido: 'Mensaje de texto y cliente',
  ImagenTemplate: {}
}
que esta pasando we  {
  IdMensaje: 5,
  TipoMensaje: 'correoElectronico',
  TipoInteresado: 'Cliente',
  Contenido: 'Mensaje de texto y cliente',
  ImagenTemplate: <Buffer 5b 6f 62 6a 65 63 74 20 4f 62 6a 65 63 74 5d>
}
tipomensaje->  true  tipointeresado  true
datos actualizados -->    {
  IdMensaje: null,
  TipoMensaje: 'sms',
  TipoInteresado: 'Cliente',
  Contenido: 'no funciona :/',
  ImagenTemplate: ''
}
que esta pasando we  {
  IdMensaje: 1,
  TipoMensaje: 'sms',
  TipoInteresado: 'Cliente',
  Contenido: 'sms cliente',
  ImagenTemplate: null
}
tipomensaje->  true  tipointeresado  true
```

handlers

```
'use strict';

const MensajeController = require('../controllers/MensajeController');

module.exports = {
  name: 'Mensaje',
  version: '1.0.0',
  register: async (server) => {

    server.route([
      {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/mensaje',
        handler: MensajeController.findMensaje,
        options: {
          description: 'List all mensajes',
          tags: ['api'],
        },
      },
      {
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/mensaje',
        handler: MensajeController.createMensaje,
        options: {
          description: 'Create mensaje',
          tags: ['api'],
        },
      },
      {
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/updatemensaje',
        handler: MensajeController.updateMensaje,
        options: {
          description: 'Update mensaje',
          tags: ['api'],
        },
      },
      {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/mensaje/{id}',
        handler: MensajeController.getMensaje,
        options: {
          description: 'Get mensaje by its {id}',
          tags: ['api'],
        },
      },
      {
        method: 'DELETE',
        path: '/mensaje/{id}',
        handler: MensajeController.deleteMensaje,
        options: {
          description: 'Delete mensaje',
          tags: ['api'],
        },
      },
    ]);
  }
};
```

Comment: Esto lo estas corriendo localmente? De ser así lo más seguro es que tengas acceso al log del servidor por cada petición que realizas a esa api, revisa la consola de node y edita la pregunta para agregar el error que te está saliendo para poder saber donde está el problema

Comment: Cual es el nombre de ese ORM que estas usando desde node?

Comment: Si esos logs se están ejecutando con los datos que te están fallando lo más probable es que el llamado a `seqMensaje.update(...)` este fallando.

Comment: Hola, si esta en local, la consola del node, seria la del backend ?, no me muestra errores.. solo los mensajes que deje arriba

Comment: Si, la consola de nodejs es la del backend, la terminal donde corres tu api, debería mostrarte errores, si no te los muestra es porque debe haber algún handler interceptando los errores silenciosamente, si estas usando expressjs te recomiendo agregar algún logger middleware como [morgan](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/morgan.html) para que puedas ver lo que sucede con tus peticiones, es super importante, de otra forma no vas a poder saber porque falla tu código del backend

Comment: @MauroAguilar, la verdad me corchaste un poco, buscare y pues busque handler en el codigo y puse eso al final pero buscare a ver que puede estarme capturando el error

Answer (score 1):

Puede ser que sea tu forma de declarar ImagenTemplate en orm?

```
 ImagenTemplate:{
        type: DataTypes.BLOB,
        allowNull:false
    }
```

Los 4 que te fallan tienen ImagenTemplate en null

Comment: hola, pues el image no es necesario y en el formulario solo pide image en caso de que sea un correo, y esto lo hice la semana pasada, funciono bien, ahora estoy retomando y encontre esta falla, igual puse el allowNull como true y no funciono :/

Comment: Lo otro que veo es que cuando te falla ImagenTemplate va como una string vacía, cuando te funciona le mandas un { }.

Comment: si se;or, muchas gracias, solo era mandarle un "null"